# Sharepoint - Get view in XML format with row limit set off

Tags: xml, sharepoint, view, get

All

Can anyone tell me how I can disable the 'row limit' in following function:
<>/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?Cmd=Display&List={GUID}&VIEW={GUID}&XMLDATA=TRUE

Currently, each time when I create a view, it has a default row limit set to 100, so when I use this function it only returns the first 100 rows.

So I always have to change the settings of the view, and update the default row-limit.

Is there a parameter I can but in this view, to disable this row limit, and take all the rows? Or overwrite the row limit in this URL?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

adding parameter '&RowLimit=0' also works, limiting fields to the default view. Query=* gets you all rows and all fields in the schema.

Answer (score -1):

http://WebApp/[site]/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?Cmd=Display&List={ListGuid}&Query=*&XMLDATA=TRUE